# How set different colors for different selected tabs of a JTabbedPane?

Tags: swing, jtabbedpane

I'm trying to create a JTabbedPane with tabs that will have different colors when selected. For example, let's say I have tabs A, B, and C. If a tab is not selected, then the tab color will be the default. If tab A is selected, then the tab color will change to red. If tab B is selected, then the tab color will change to green. If tab C is selected, then the tab color will change to yellow. How can I achieve this behavior? The closest method I could find was calling `UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", Color.RED)` but this sets the color of all selected tabs to red.

Answer (score 1):

Add a listener for the selection and then change the background accordingly.  Something like:

```
pane.addChangeListener( new ChangeListener() {
   public void stateChanged( ChangeEvent e ) {
      int index = pane.getSelectedIndex();
      if( index == 0 ) {
        pane.setBackgroundAt( 0, Color.RED );
      } else if( index == 1 ) {
        pane.setBackgroundAt( 0, Color.GREEN);
      }
      ...
   }
} );
```

Comment: This doesn't have quite the behavior I'm try to produce. Using your method, all the tabs start off with the default color. Once a tab is selected, the tab color changes to the color stated in the code but what is actually painted is the default selected tab color. The color that is passed into `setBackgroundAt()` doesn't appear until after a new tab has been selected.

Comment: @lalalainexd that's an example only. You can change the code of stateChanged method as you need, for example setting background color back to default (using null) for tabs not selected.

Comment: @lalalainexd   

int index = pane.getSelectedIndex();
Color selectedColor = index==0?Color.red:index==1?Color.green:Color.yellow;
for(int i=0; int < pane.getTabCount(); i++) pane.setBackgroundAt(i, i==index?selectedColor:null);